# How to call one perl script in another perl script?

Tags: perl

I want to call one perl script in main script and print the output. I have no idea how to do it. Any inputs please.

`abcd.pl` is my main script and have few small script that written separately I want to call them in main script and print the output.

Comment: Refactor it into a module, then `use` it.

Answer (score 3):

file `1.pl`:

```
print "i'm perl\n"
```

in file `2.pl`:

```
$t = `perl 1.pl`;
print $t;
```

and run file `2.pl`

```
perl 2.pl
```

OUtput is:

```
i'm perl
```

***OR use `require`***:

file `1.pl`:

```
sub test{
        print "i'm perl\n";
}
1;
```

file `2.pl`:

```
require '1.pl';
test();
```

OUTPUT:

```
i'm perl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call subs from another script, you can use 'require abcd.pl',

or export methods via [Exporter](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Exporter-5.70/lib/Exporter.pm).

To do exactly what I think you are asking, use backticks `` ( note these are not quotes ).

like

```
my $var = `abcd.pl`;
```

Otherwise, if you need more control ( and perhaps generally a better idea ),

you can

```
use IPC::System::Simple;
```

Here is the [CPAN link](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm)

Comment: thanks , can we pass argument when use backticks ``
ex: 
my $var = `abcd.pl`ARGV=[0];

abcd.pl need argument input

Comment: Indeed you can. I suppose you have figured this out by now, as it works exactly as one might suspect: just add the args as if you typed in command line.