# Simple cgi script fails with permission denied error

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, rhel

Perl CGI script fails with

```
Can't locate /home/testdir/first.pl:  /home/testdir/first.pl:  
Permission denied at /var/www/cgi-bin/first.cgi line 2.
```

and

```
End of script output before headers: first.cgi  in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
```

This is an rhel8 system with apache 2.4

I have tried moving `first.pl` around to different locations and modifying `first.cgi` to point to `first.pl`.
`first.cgi` executes if I place `first.pl` in `/var/www`, but not `/home/testdir`, `/var` or other directories

In `httpd.conf`, I set permissions for `/home/testdir/` to the same as `/var/www`, shown below, and restarted apache

```
<Directory "/home/testdir">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Out of frustration, I then changed the permissions for `/var/www` to `Require all denied` and restarted apache.  `first.cgi` still successfully ran `first.pl` when I pointed it to `/var/www` with the permissions changed to `Require all denied`.

I also disable `suexec` and recieved the same errors when pointing `first.cgi` to `/home/testdir`

The permissions for `first.pl` are 755 in `/home/testdir` as well as `/var/www` and the user and group are both root.

The permissions for `home`, `testdir`, `var` and `www` are all 755 and the users and groups are all root

**first.cgi**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require '/home/testdir/first.pl';
test();
```

**first.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub test{
    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "Hello, World.";
}
first;
```

The script should display "Hello, World". on the webpage.  Instead, it displays:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: Where is the `first` sub on the last line of `first.pl` defined?

Comment: Just a question, why are you using `cgi` in 2019? `:)`

Comment: This will be a UNIX permissions/ACLs/SELinux issue. The id which the apache process is running as doen't have read access to first.pl and/or search permissions for the intervening directories. In fact if your server is running SELinux, then that would normally be set up so that apache processes specifically can't access anything outside of /var/www etc.

Comment: I'm running CGI because I have inherited certain tasks that dont have a working,modern replacement yet.  This is just a sample script I wrote to debug an issue I am having porting them to rhel8.

Comment: I actully successfully ran the script as apache with sudo -u apache ./first.cgi to check Linux permissions.

Comment: first sub isn't defined, I've displayed all of both test scripts.  I adapted them from this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778575/how-to-call-one-perl-script-in-another-perl-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave Mitchell's comment is correct.  After entering sudo setenforce permissive on the command line, the script runs as expected.